# Can I use a union mapping a list of member against a struct?

Tags: c++, unions

I'd like to access member of a union by member name or by a "wrapped" structs, [such as](https://godbolt.org/z/x6bneorn6):

```
#include <iostream>

struct MyClass
{   
    union {
        int t1;
        float t2;
        struct {
            int t1;
            float t2; 
        } mySharedData;
    };

    MyClass() {
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass myClass;

    myClass.t2 = 10.1;
    std::cout << myClass.mySharedData.t2 << std::endl;
}
```

but it seems that t2 and mySharedData.t2 are not pointing to the same memory. Is there a way to do somethings like this? So I can access to a sub-group of members by its name or by grouped struct.

Comment: If I read `union` in a c++ question nowadays, my brain automatically replaces this with `std::variant`.

Comment: "t2 and mySharedData.t2 are not pointing to the same memory" why would they?

Comment: Why do you need the union here? Why not just use the struct?

Comment: active member of the union is either `t1` or `t2` or `mySharedData` and `mySharedData.t2` is the second member, but when `t2` is the active member it is the first

Comment: @interjay so I can deal within the class directly with member variable, and outside "copy" a group of members by simply indicate the struct name

Comment: In a union, the members overlap each other in memory. What you're asking for is not a union.

Comment: In C++, when you write to a member of a union, you can only read from that exact member. Reading any other member will lead to *undefined behavior*. You write to `t2` and read from `mySharedData`, which are different members. Which is not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you just want "alias" for your members.

`union` is NOT the solution.

You might, with a little different syntax, have those alias.

With

```
struct MyClass
{
    struct {
        int t1 = 0;
        float t2 = 0; 
    } mySharedData;

    MyClass() {}

    // const version omitted for simplicity.
#if VERSION_1
    auto operator ->() { return &mySharedData; }
#else
    auto& t1() { return mySharedData.t1; }
    auto& t2() { return mySharedData.t2; }
#endif
};
```

You might have

```
myClass->t1 = 42;     // version 1 o->t1 instead of o.t1
myClass.t2() = 10.1f; // version 2 o.t2() instead of o.t2()

std::cout << myClass.mySharedData.t2; // and regular access.
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hzP3cqxvb)

Answer (score 1):

Only one member of the union is the active member. The layout is either of the following:

```
  [  int  ]            t1 is active member
  [  float  ]          t2 is active member
  [  int   float  ]    mySharedData is active member
```

When either `t1` or `mySharedData` is the active member you can read the from the other. Details are beyond the scope of the question. Just a warning: It is easy to run into undefined behavior. And the situation is somewhat diffuse, because many compilers offer extensions that defer from the more strict standard.

However, no matter what compiler extension, you cannot use a union to have both `t1` and `mySharedData.t1` and `t2` and `mySharedData.t2` overlap (unless the union contains two structes of same type, which defeats the purpose of doing this).

What you want to achive cannot be done with a union.